# Validation ErrorMessage value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

How to emit custom validator error messages for an entity like this?:

Receipts exeeded invoice amount  of 15000

My property

```
[InvoiceAmountNotExeeded(ErrorMessage = "Receipts exeeded invoice amount  of {0}")]
public int Amount {get; set; }
```

In validator:

```
var errorMsg = FormatErrorMessage(string.Format(validationContext.DisplayName,invoice.Amount))
```

Problem is  I m getting: Receipts exeeded invoice amount of Amount. 
Note how it is writting the property name instead of property value. Advice?

> EDIT: Code added

```
public class InvoiceAmountNotExeededAttribute : ValidationAttribute {

        public InvoiceAmountNotExeededAttribute()
        {            
        } 

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var factId = ....;
            var db = new Entities();
            var fact = db.Invoices.Find(factId);
            var amountRecibos = ...;
            var amount = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            if (amountRecibos + amount > fact.Amount ){
                var errorMsg = FormatErrorMessage(string.Format(validationContext.DisplayName,invoice.Amount));
                return new ValidationResult(errorMsg);
            }            
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too little information to solve the problem. string.Format will not take the property name but its value as you want. It is interesting where does validationContext.DisplayName come from.

Comment: @mr100 validationContext is the parameter passed to IsValid method defined in ValidationAttribute base class. That method is invoked by the runtime.

Comment: Your answer did not give me any hint. Without posting more code I think nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: @mr100 oh so you downvoted?

Comment: Yes, because in my opinion this question does not provide enough information to solve the problem and this is a reason to vote it down. Please provide more information and I will remove my vote.

Comment: Did you try override FormatErrorMessage in the InvoiceAmountNotExeededAttribute ? Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010146/asp-net-mvc-adding-custom-errormessage-that-incorporates-displayname-to-custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have this behaviour is because you refer to validationContext.DisplayName which by default is set to property name ("Amount" in your case). So for you string.Format(validationContext.DisplayName,invoice.Amount) returns just "Amount". Instead of this try to apply this:

```
var errorMsg = FormatErrorMessage(invoice.Amount.ToString());
return new ValidationResult(errorMsg);
```

This way you will pass to FormatErroMessage not DisplayName for your property but Amount value instead and FormatErrorMessage will use it with pattern from ErrorMessage attribute property. So this should give you what you want.